# Are there good Java libraries that facilitate building interactive shell-style applications?

Tags: java

I need to write a simple shell-style application in Java. It would be nice to use a library that takes care of parsing commands and takes care of things like flags and optional/mandatory parameters...

Something that has built-in TAB completion would be particularly great.

Comment: bill the lizard is incorrect... it is not an EXACT duplicate... unless i am mistaken, there is a difference between shell style and command line applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) for editing and [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/usage.html) for command line parsing.

Comment: Take a look at `cliche` : https://code.google.com/p/cliche/ Super simple and powerful enough to cover a wide range of needs.

Answer (score 3):

[BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) ?

Comment: Is this actively maintained? The website doesn't have any release dates, and docs for version 2 aren't available yet.

Comment: Lately, they are saying that its going to end up being part of a J2SE release at some point, and so I would say this should be the real answer.

Answer (score 2):

I much prefer either [JewelCLI](http://jewelcli.sourceforge.net/) or [args4j](https://args4j.dev.java.net/) over Apache Commons CLI.

There is a good, if somewhat inflammatory, roundup of several java CLI options parsers [here](http://javathink.blogspot.com/2008/04/why-does-parsing-arguments-in-java-suck.html).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on JBoss Forge (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/FORGE/Home).

Its a build shell based on Java CDI Plugins and it an be extended by custom plugins.
I my case I wrote a GWT Plugin based on Forge (https://github.com/xandrox/forge-gwtplugin).

```
public class ExamplePlugin implements Plugin {

    @Inject private ShellPrompt prompt;

    @Command("run")
    public void run(PipeOut out, @Option(name="value") final String arg){
        out.println("Executed command with value: " + arg);
    }
}
```